# Is it possible to customise autopep8 formatting?

Tags: autopep8

For example, dictionaries are currently formatted from this:

```
return {
    'v2': {'type': 'some_type', 'path_definitions': path.to.some.Module},
    'raw': {'type': 'raw'},
}
```

to this:

```
return {
    'v2: {
        'type': 'some_type',
        'path_definitions': path.to.some.Module},
    'raw': {
        'type': 'raw'},
}
```

Can I somehow change the way autopep8 converts the code so that I have the closing brackets of the inner dictionaries on a new line rather than on the same line?